# Sharing props with composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is there any way to share props between components using the composition API, or should I still resort to mixins for that?

For example, I have a "visible" prop that I want to reuse on 5 components. How can I define it in 1 common place and reuse it with the composition API?

With a mixin I would have done it the old fashioned way:

```
const mixin = {
   props: { visibile: { type: Boolean: required: false } }
}
```

Used in the component:

```
mixins: [theMixinAbove]
```

How can I accomplish this using the composition API?

Comment: I don’t really understand what you mean by “sharing” props. Each component has its own props.

Comment: The API for mixins doesn't seem to have changed in Vue 3 and, as far as I can tell, there isn't any other way to achieve this.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Alright, but if I resort to mixins with composition API, I can't get type safety, right?

Comment: I can't actually get a mixin to work with props in the way you've described. Have you tested it and know that it works?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding you but yeah I've done it multiple times with the options API, it's just a matter of reusing a mixin. Right now I'm thinking about using `PropType<MyProps>` instead, guess that's a viable option...

Comment: You  can use - not  PROPS.
In the PARENT const ANYthing = ref( variableTOchange) -> PROVIDE,
then you may INJECT in CHILDRENS-all-levels.
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but I think you'll need to implement props as-well in a similar manner, and you can't do it during setup because at that point, the props are already expected.

For example you can define a function that lives with your other function you would use during setup, and then destructure it into the rest of your props

`props:{myInternalProp:String, ...withVisibilityProps()},`

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.component('my-component', {
  template: '<h1>My Component is {{visiblity}}</h1>',
  props:{...withVisibilityProps()},
  setup(props){
    return({...withVisibility(props)})
  }
})

function withVisibility(props) {
  return {visiblity:Vue.ref(props.visible?"visible":"not visible")};
}
function withVisibilityProps() {
    return {visible:Boolean};
}

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component :visible="true"></my-component>
  <my-component :visible="false"></my-component>
</div>
```

note that the setup function is used to handle the `visibility` variable. If you only need the prop, you can skip the `withVisibility` and `setup`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `script setup` and use `defineProps` inside the composable.
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits